# SSL Provider: [error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed:self-signed certificate]

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu

I am facing this error when I run this command in my ubuntu_22.04 terminal

command: `sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA`

Error Message:

> Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server : SSL Provider: [error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed:self-signed certificate].
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server : Client unable to establish connection. For solutions related to encryption errors, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2226722.

I am trying to login with the SQL Server.

Comment: since it's on localhost, you can try disablign encryption ? as per the link in the error message.